# I have added a Row using a condition (If/Else Statement), how should I add a formula to the newly inserted row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Here is the code I have used.

```
function myFunction() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var activeSheet = ss.getSheetByName("WOF")
  ss.getRange("B14:F14").setFormula("=INDEX($H2:$BE2,INT(COLUMN()+(ROWS(B$14:B14)-1.1)*5))");
  var cellp2 = activeSheet.getRange("p2").getValue();
  if(cellp2 > 0){
      activeSheet.insertRowsAfter(14, 1);
    }
  var cellu2 = activeSheet.getRange("u2").getValue();
  if(cellu2 > 0){
      activeSheet.insertRowsAfter(14, 1);
    }
  var cellz2 = activeSheet.getRange("z2").getValue();
  if(cellz2 > 0){
      activeSheet.insertRowsAfter(14, 1);
  }
  var cellae2 = activeSheet.getRange("ae2").getValue();
  if(cellae2 > 0){
      activeSheet.insertRowsAfter(14, 1);
  }
  var cellaj2 = activeSheet.getRange("aj2").getValue();
  if(cellaj2 > 0){
      activeSheet.insertRowsAfter(14, 1);
  }
  var cellao2 = activeSheet.getRange("ao2").getValue();
  if(cellao2 > 0){
      activeSheet.insertRowsAfter(14, 1);
  }
  var cellat2 = activeSheet.getRange("at2").getValue();
  if(cellat2 > 0){
      activeSheet.insertRowsAfter(14, 1);
  }
  var cellay2 = activeSheet.getRange("ay2").getValue();
  if(cellay2 > 0){
      activeSheet.insertRowsAfter(14, 1);
  }
  var cellbd2 = activeSheet.getRange("bd2").getValue();
  if(cellbd2 > 0){
      activeSheet.insertRowsAfter(14, 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Formula needs to be copied down only if a row in inserted.

Comment: Still does not copy down the formula to the inserted rows

Comment: Simplify your code. Do you need to insert a single row, if any of the listed ranges has a positive value? Or insert one row for each of the listed ranges with a positive value? Either way, you can use the D.R.Y. principle to make updating this script simple.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [DRY (don't repeat yourself) guideline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), we want to reduce code duplication as much as possible: any duplicated cases that could be handled together, should be. In your script, you repeat the same behavior on a number of ranges, and have written (the same) code for each one, changing only the string passed to `getRange` (and using a new variable name to hold the [`Range`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) reference:

```
var cellp2 = activeSheet.getRange("p2").getValue();
if (cellp2 > 0) {
  activeSheet.insertRowsAfter(14, 1);
}
```

A better approach would store the range names in an [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), which we could then iterate with a `for` loop, or use the `Array#forEach` method.

```
const rangesToCheck = [
  "p2",
  "u2",
  ...
];
```

If only 1 row needs to be inserted if any of the ranges meet the criteria, we should use the [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) loop, as we can exit the loop prematurely:

```
for (var i = 0; i < rangesToCheck.length; ++i) {
  if (activeSheet.getRange(rangesToCheck[i]).getValue() > 0) {
    activeSheet.insertRowsAfter(14, 1);
    break; // exit the "nearest" loop scope.
  }
}
```

[`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is explicitly used when you want to do the same thing for each element in the `Array`. I.e., "For each" range, if its value is > 0, add a new row after row 14.

```
rangesToCheck.forEach(function (a1) {
  if (activeSheet.getRange(a1).getValue() > 0) {
    activeSheet.insertRowsAfter(14, 1);
  }
});
```

This last case - multiple row insertion - can be improved by first counting the number of rows to insert, and then doing a single insert (i.e. changing the number of inserted rows from `1` to `numPositiveValues`:

```
var numPositiveValues = 0;
rangesToCheck.forEach(function (a1) {
  if (activeSheet.getRange(a1).getValue() > 0) {
    ++numPositiveValues;
  }
});
// Add as many rows as desired:
if (numPositiveValues > 0) {
  activeSheet.insertRowsAfter(14, numPositiveValues);
}
```

We can further optimize the above approaches (both single- and multiple-row insertions), using the relatively-new [`RangeList`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list) class to acquire disjoint `Range`s [from the same worksheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRangeList(String)). An example use for multiple-row insertion is:

```
var numPositiveValues = 0;
const rl = activeSheet.getRangeList(rangesToCheck);
rl.getRanges().forEach(function (rg) {
  if (rg.getValue() > 0) {
    ++numPositiveValues;
  }
});
if (numPositiveValues > 0) {
  activeSheet.insertRowsAfter(14, numPositiveValues);
}
```

---

Simplifying your code in this manner means you now only need to handle setting values (and/or formatting, formulas, etc.) for the inserted rows in 1 place, rather than every place where you might add rows:

```
if (numPositiveValues > 0) {
  var insertedRangeToModify = activeSheet.insertRowsAfter(14, numPositiveValues)
    .getRange(14, /** start column index */, numPositiveValues, /** end column index */);
  // insertedRangeToModify.setValue(...)
  // insertedRangeToModify.setValues(...)
  // insertedRangeToModify.setFormula(...)
  // insertedRangeToModify.setFormulas(...)
  // insertedRangeToModify.setFormulaR1C1(...)
  // insertedRangeToModify.setFormulasR1C1(...)
  // etc.
}
```

Additional references

- [Meaning of `const` in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const#Description)
- [`break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break)
- [`Sheet#insertRowsAfter`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertRowsAfter(Integer,Integer))
- [`Sheet#getRange(row, col, numRows, numCols)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer))